# Good MOSFET for high-side switching 200mA from 5V logic

Tags: mosfet, switches

I want to switch the power on/off to the WIFI module using an IO pin of a microcontroller, peak current is 200mA, average current 100mA. Which MOSFET(part number) should I use?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fX6eol.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Bob. Oh. A PMOSFET.

Comment: You might look at the parts specifically marketed for switching USB VBus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it your circuit is wrong - it's showing an N channel mosfet wired as a source follower and this means you're likely to get about 2 or 3 volts out of it when "switched on".

You need a p channel mosfet with source tied to incoming power and drain connected to the output. Pulling the gate low will activate the FET, returning the gate to 5V will deactivate the fet but make sure you get one with \$V_{GS(threshold)}\$ quite low - maybe about -1V typical and -2V max.

The device Wouter has linked (IRF7205) might work OK but it's threshold range might mean sometimes it doesn't work (if you built a hundred maybe 5 wouldn't work as expected).

Answer (score 0):

In such a situation I use an IRF7205. There must be lots of alternatives.